# Illuminate an LED when a ground switch is open

Tags: transistors, led, switches

I have a switch that connects the negative side of a solenoid to ground when closed and I need to have an LED that is illuminated when the switch is open. I was thinking of using a transistor to do this but I am not sure exactly how to incorporate it with the solenoid. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: (1) Please post a link to the datasheet for the switch.  (2) What voltage is used to activate the solenoid?  What other voltages (if any) are available in your setup?

Comment: The solenoid gets it's voltage from a 24V rail which is currently all I have. The switch is just an on-off 20A rated rocker switch.

Comment: Judging from your comment, the LED is separate from the switch.  (The LED isn't built into the switch.)

Comment: That is correct, the LED is not part of the switch. I need the LED to tell me when the switch is open by illuminating when it is and turning off once the switch is closed.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv3Tf4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. LED on when SW1 is open.*

How it works:

- When SW1 is opened up to 5 mA (24 V / 4k7) will flow through SOLN, R1 and D1. The circuit relies on the solenoid having a high holding current (say, > 20 mA) relative to the required LED current so that the LED current does not keep the solenoid on when SW1 is opened.
- When SW1 is closed R1/D1 is shorted out and the LED will turn off.
- When SW1 is opened the inductive spike which might damage D1 is shunted by D2.
- If you wish to be more precise with the D1 current calculation then add in the DC resistance of SOLN to the current calculation for the LED.

Comment: This worked and was a super easy solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the solenoid normally draws much more current than an LED, just connect a resistor and LED from the negative side of the solenoid to ground. A few milliamperes will flow through the solenoid when the switch is open, but that probably won't cause you any trouble.

Comment: You must also have a reverse diode from switch to opposite rail rated for load current to protect the switch and LED included.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Yes, good point.

Answer (score 0):

Just whipped this up, hopefully it helps :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIr7UP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is open:

- The gate of the N-Channel is pulled up to whatever voltage is set by the divider. Usually you wouldn't even need the divider, and could simply tap onto the end of the solenoid. But the MOSFET you choose most likely won't be able to handle Vgs = 24V, so use the divider to set an appropriate voltage. Here I have set it to 8V, which will absolutely turn on 99% of MOSFETs, but is also well under the typical 12-15V max Vgs rating. While the solenoid is in series, there is 0A flowing into the gate at steady-state, and so it's as if the solenoid isn't even there and is a short-circuit.

When the switch is closed:

- The input of the divider will be 0V, and so the gate of the N-Channel MOSFET will be driven to 0V. Therefore, Vgs = 0V. So the MOSFET will be off and so the LED will also be off.

You can play with the value of R2 for different LED brightness levels. For a 24V rail, and a typical 3Vish forward voltage drop LED, 1K is a good starting point for 20mA which is your typical hobbyist LED current.

Also make sure you choose high-impedances for the divider, like I have here. This is because "technically" the solenoid is always on, as current flows through the divider. But if you make these hundred Kilo to Mega range, the solenoid is practically off and chewing next to 0W of power.